# Swift Firebase load array of arrays

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load an array of arrays with Firebase and would appreciate any help on how to do so. Thanks! Picture is of database.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to observe `defense` then inside the callback

```
self.ref.child("defense").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in 
   let res = snap.value as! [String:[String:Int]]
   let all = Array(res.values).map { Array($0.values) } // [[-1,-1,-1],[...]]
})
```

Comment: its giving me 'Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1f4932630) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1f49335f8).'

Comment: tell me what this gives `print(type(of:snap.value))`

Comment: its a Optional<Any>

Comment: and this `let res = snap.value as! [[String:Any]]`

Comment: it says res is a ([[String: Any]]). The program stops and shows the varbiable values in the feed. No error msg just program breaks.

Comment: Do you need any more information, or just stuck. Sorry just trying to get this error resolved